# Why caring about the dimensions and the axis of computation when calculating the derivative of the bias vector in backpropagation?

Tags: python, backpropagation

In order to create a linear backward function for my first deep neural network I wanted to calculate the derivative of $b$, the bias vector in the l<sup>th</sup> layer, $db^{[l]} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L} }{\partial b^{[l]}} = \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i = 1}^{m} dZ^{[l](i)}$ following an [IPython notebook tutorial](https://github.com/Kulbear/deep-learning-coursera/blob/master/Neural%20Networks%20and%20Deep%20Learning/Building%20your%20Deep%20Neural%20Network%20-%20Step%20by%20Step.ipynb). Starting innocently with

```
db = (1./m)*np.sum(dZ)
```

I quickly noticed that this wasn't enough to computer it as far as it seemed t create dimension errors. So I added some few parameters taht made the job but I don't understand why :

```
db = (1./m)*np.sum(dZ,axis=1,keepdims=True)
```

Therefore, why do we have to care about the dimensions and the axis of computation when calculating the derivative of the bias vector in backpropagation ?

Comment: your python notebook is behind the wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to understand your problem is to think of the intended dimension of what you call `db`. Since you have a bunch of neurons in the layer, your `db` should be a vector - one element per neuron in the layer. However, `np.sum(dZ)` returns a scalar. It adds up all elements of the arrays going through every column and row.